# Is it "open up" or "open"?

Tags: verbs

> I **open up** myself very well
>   I **open** myself very well

For emotions, vulnerabilities, which form is right or better?
Does "open up" exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Open up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/open-up) to someone*** is the correct expression: 
​

> - to start to talk more about yourself and your feelings:
>
>   - *I've never opened up to anyone like I do to you.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Note also:

***[Open up to something:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/open+up+with+someone)***

> - to become more accepting of someone or something.
>
>   - *Finally, he opened up to the suggestion that he should leave. Finally the boss opened up to the notion of Tom as a manager.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms)

Comment: Yes, you are certainly correct that "open up" is acceptable but you don't address the examples in the question at all, which are very poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Both are generally viable options but neither of them work in your sample sentences.

We use both "open" and "open up" to mean that you're speaking freely about a subject or welcoming other things.

> I need to learn how to open up more with my family.
>   Please be open and honest with me about how you feel.
>   Opening up and talking about your issues will improve communication.

That said, being used with "myself" often actually requires placing the "myself" between "open" and "up".

> I'm opening myself up to criticism so that I can be a better person.

Saying "I open up myself" sounds a bit odd because of the word order. [Here's an example](http://www.positivelypresent.com/2009/04/are-you-open-.html) that I think is the most similar to what you're trying to say:

> *I may also be surprised by what I hear when I open myself up to the words of others instead of staying trapped in my own little head.*

And, still, "up" is not *necessary*, though it's probably more common. The sentence above could easily omit "up" and still be perfectly acceptable.